# opening a zipped excel file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, zip

I am trying to open a zipped excel file with `pandas`

When I try

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlopen
import io

url = 'https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/fut_disagg_xls_2020.zip'
file =zipfile.ZipFile((io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())))
file_name = file.namelist()[0]
pd.read_excel(file.open(file_name))
```

I get an `UnsupportedOperation: seek` error. Any ideas how to read this file?

**EDIT**

Here is the trace:

```
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-874d52ab10ad> in <module>
      7 file =zipfile.ZipFile((io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())))
      8 file_name = file.namelist()[0]
----> 9 pd.read_excel(file.open(file_name))

~/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols)
    302 
    303     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 304         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    305     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    306         raise ValueError(

~/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine)
    849             engine = "xlrd"
    850             if isinstance(path_or_buffer, (BufferedIOBase, RawIOBase)):
--> 851                 if _is_ods_stream(path_or_buffer):
    852                     engine = "odf"
    853             else:

~/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in _is_ods_stream(stream)
    798         Boolean indication that this is indeed an ODS file or not
    799     """
--> 800     stream.seek(0)
    801     is_ods = False
    802     if stream.read(4) == b"PK\003\004":

UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, your code prints dataframe with `[8480 rows x 188 columns]
` (Python 3.8, Pandas 1.1.3)

Comment: I cannot reproduce either and get the exact same as Andrej (same versions). Are you sure it is that exact code that you are running? Could you post the entire stack traceback with line numbers etc. in the question?

Comment: This is the exact code I am running. Python 3.6.12, pandas 1.13

Comment: Added the traceback

Comment: @MHorsley I tried your code with Python3.6 and yes, I've got seek error. So it depends on Python version

Comment: Interesting, I guess i'll update my python

Comment: @MHorsley I've posted an answer with workaround.

Comment: Use zipfile object's read method, `df = pd.read_excel(file.read(file_name))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in Python's version. In Python3.8 the script works as is. In Python3.6, add `.read()` in `pd.read_excel()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlopen
import io

url = 'https://www.cftc.gov/files/dea/history/fut_disagg_xls_2020.zip'
file =zipfile.ZipFile((io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())))
file_name = file.namelist()[0]
df = pd.read_excel(file.open(file_name).read())  # <-- add .read()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                              Market_and_Exchange_Names  As_of_Date_In_Form_YYMMDD Report_Date_as_MM_DD_YYYY  ...                Contract_Units CFTC_SubGroup_Code  FutOnly_or_Combined
0                    WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE                     201013                2020-10-13  ...  (CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)                A10              FutOnly
1                    WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE                     201006                2020-10-06  ...  (CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)                A10              FutOnly
2                    WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE                     200929                2020-09-29  ...  (CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)                A10              FutOnly
3                    WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE                     200922                2020-09-22  ...  (CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)                A10              FutOnly
4                    WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE                     200915                2020-09-15  ...  (CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)                A10              FutOnly
...                                                 ...                        ...                       ...  ...                           ...                ...                  ...
8475  MINI JAPAN C&F NAPHTHA - NEW YORK MERCANTILE E...                     200901                2020-09-01  ...             (100 METRIC TONS)                N10              FutOnly
8476  MINI JAPAN C&F NAPHTHA - NEW YORK MERCANTILE E...                     200825                2020-08-25  ...             (100 METRIC TONS)                N10              FutOnly
8477  MINI JAPAN C&F NAPHTHA - NEW YORK MERCANTILE E...                     200818                2020-08-18  ...             (100 METRIC TONS)                N10              FutOnly
8478  MINI JAPAN C&F NAPHTHA - NEW YORK MERCANTILE E...                     200811                2020-08-11  ...             (100 METRIC TONS)                N10              FutOnly
8479  MINI JAPAN C&F NAPHTHA - NEW YORK MERCANTILE E...                     200728                2020-07-28  ...             (100 METRIC TONS)                N10              FutOnly

[8480 rows x 188 columns]
```